# Using as much as in a phrase involving units of measurement

Tags: grammar

Is it proper to say as much as 700 thous. cub. m of wastewater or you need to put  as many as instead?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Nouns of volume, weight, length, etc are non-count, thus use 'as much as'.